# Bijections and composite functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $X$ be a set and let $f : X$ $\longrightarrow$ $X$ be a function. Show that $f$ is a bijection if and only if there is a function $g : X$ $\longrightarrow$ $X$ such that $f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = x$ $\forall$ $x$$\in$$X$.

I know I should use the definitions of injective and surjective here but I do not know how to apply them. I realize to prove the iff statement I need to show both sides imply each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assume that $f: X\longrightarrow X$ is a bijection.  Then there is an inverse function call it $f^{-1}: X \longrightarrow X$.  Then we have for each $x\in X$ that,

$$f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x $$

Now assume that there is some function $g:X\longrightarrow X$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x$,  for each $x\in X$.  Then I will show $f$ is a bijection.  Let $x\in X$.  I know that $f(g(x))=x$  Therfore we have an element $g(x)\in X$ such that $f(g(x))=x$  So we have surjectivity.  Now Let $f(x)=f(y)$.  This tells me that

$$g(f(x))=g(f(y)) \Rightarrow x=y$$

Therefore we have injectivity.  Therefore, $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: I follow the second assumption of the existence of g implying the bijectivity of f. However, does the first part actually prove anything? I think the point of the problem was to construct g (the inverse). How would we do this? Perhaps using the pre-image, but more specifically.

Comment: Since $f: X \longrightarrow X$ is bijective, then any element $y\in X$ can be written as $y=f(x)$ for some unique $x \in X$.  Define $f^{-1}:X \longrightarrow X$ to be the map $f(x)\mapsto x$.  You're correct, I should have defined what the inverse map actually is :)

Answer (score 0):

$(\Leftarrow)$: $f(g(x)) = x$ for all $x$ leads to $f$ is surjective ($g(x)$ is a pre-image of $x$). $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$ leads to $f$ is injective ($f(x) = f(y)$ then $g(f(x)) = g(f(y))$, hence $x = y$).

$(\Rightarrow)$: Put $g = f^{-1}$ (note that the set $f^{-1}(x) = \{y : f(y) = x\}$ has a unique element when $f$ is bijective), then one has $f(g(x)) = x$ for all $x$. Replace $x$ by $f(x)$, one has $f(g(f(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$. Now because $f$ is injective, $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$.